# Are wet dreams from Shaitan?

Tags: shaitan, dream, nocturnal-emission

In this [video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=PLyfPcUoivAtYLK6aIirYy65RieY1kCwBk&v=Ok-bLXlJ97Q), it states:

> "The dream when you wake up and you are all wet is from Shaitan."

I've derived that this is a wet dream.

Allah has in fact made wet dreams [al-hilm] a sign of puberty:

> “And when the children among you come to puberty [al-hilm]…”
>
> [al-Noor 24:59](https://quran.com/24/59)

This means that wet dreams are a sign of puberty but the above says that wet dreams are from Shaitan.

The possibility is that these dreams are not wet dreams and another dream that caused wetness from Shaitan but the only other thing that you wake up wet with is urine but that's not because of dreams.

**So are wet dreams from Shaitan or are these dreams another type of dream that caused wetness?**

Comment: "and you are all wet" could refer to nightmares where you sweat a lot.

Comment: @G.Bach I once heard from a doctor that when men have an orgasm their whole body emits something (other than sweat).

Comment: The video even talks about nightmares, see time mark 1:10 and on.

Comment: i think you understood wet dream incorrectly. it is an euphemism for pollution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've heard it **can be** a good sign. That is: You had lust, but didn't masturbate nor committed adultery, each time you saw a beautiful women you just turned away. Eventually Allah eased your sexual lust with a great (sexual) dream. I find it to be a beautiful mechanism for pious (young) men.

Having that said if you watched sexual movies one after another, vigorously looked at girls and didn't masturbate nor committed adultery and then had a dream then yes this is a dream created by you **following your desires** and it's not a good thing. It's just like your most other dreams that is if you hate someone a lot, you may have a dream where you're cursing the person.